# Recursive partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm trying to reuse my partial views like this:

```
<div>
<ul data-bind="foreach: DetailViewModelObject.ConfigsChild">
    <li>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: DetailViewModelObject.Id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Llave
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    Valor
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: DetailViewModelObject.Key" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="..." class="btn bg-primary" data-bind="click: DetailViewModelObject.SetPropertiesKeyCommand" style="margin: 5px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: DetailViewModelObject.Value" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="..." class="btn bg-primary" data-bind="click: DetailViewModelObject.SetPropertiesValueCommand" style="margin: 5px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Agregar configuración" class="btn bg-warning" data-bind="click: DetailViewModelObject.AddConfigCommandChild" style="margin: 5px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    @Html.Partial("~/Views/ApplicationConfig/_PartialApplicationConfigDetail.cshtml")
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But appears the follow error:

> **StackOverFlowException on mscorlib.dll**

And the process ends ...

So: It's posible make this? Have any of you idea how to build that?

I'm using knockout and I making a tree of class and for render to user Im reusing PartialViews them self

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception (behaviour) is absolutely normal because you are creating an **endless recursion**:

Your view renders the same view, which renders the same view, which renders the same view... and that stops when `StackOverflowException` is hit.

**Put some condition** (`if` in the view) (recursion bottom) to stop it.

Another solution I can suggest you is to use Knockout and **call an action to display the view using AJAX**.

Comment: Yes its true, I should build the view making a POST, the POST return me the view (return a partial), the data I could make some thing like: $(selector-div).html(data); and finish !! ... What do you thing about this solution ???